# Direct file access (SQlite database) with Android 10+

Tags: android, database, transactions, android-contentprovider, storage-access-framework

I have 2 apps A & B. A can download data to a sqlite database owned by B. Until now I asked the user the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and A could directly write to B's database, and thus use transactions in order to avoid altering the database if the user cancels the process.

With Android 10 direct file access does not seem to be possible anymore as we are forced to use that ****** SAF...

To still get this working I updated my apps to use a ContentProvider. However, I'm no longer able to use transactions to provide the cancel feature: the data being too heavy to fit in memory, I can't use the ContentProvider's batch insert methods (if I'm not mistaken?).

Am I stuck? Or is there a solution to grant a direct file access between two apps I own? Ideally he process would be like this:

- 1 asks B a file access
- B grants the access
- A starts a transaction
- A download file 1
- A download file 2
- [...]
- A download file n
- A commits the transaction (or rollbacks if user asked to cancel)
- A notifies B that the download is done
- B revokes the access

Is that possible?

EDIT: I need an access with the File object, in order to use the SqliteDatabaseOpenHelper class, thus grantUriPermission won't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a solution to grant a direct file access between two apps I own?

No.

> Am I stuck?

You could do:

- A download file 1
- A download file 2
- [...]
- A download file n
- A tells B "yo, I downloaded these files" by some means (see below), if the user did not cancel the operation
- B updates its own database

"By some means" could be:

- `insert()` or `update()` with your `ContentProvider`
- a command delivered by `startService()`
- `bindService()` and a call on the AIDL-defined API exposed by B's service
- a broadcast `Intent` with an explicit `Intent`
- starting an activity in B, if that would be appropriate (probably not, just mentioning for completeness)

A has a "user transaction" and can stop its downloads based on user interaction. Once the downloads are complete, B can perform the database transaction to update its own database with the details of the downloaded stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, that's what I guessed: I must either drop the transaction feature or have to copy all the data from A to B at the end of the download. In both cases that really sucks.

Comment: @TimAutin: I guess that I don't fully grok "the transaction feature". You could have B expose a AIDL-declared bound service with whatever API that you want. If you want A to be able to put stuff in the database for every download, and to be able to declare transaction bounds, you can have B do all of that by means of the bound service. Basically, whatever function calls A would make to the database would be made to B, which would turn around and make them to the database. Personally, I prefer more coarse-grained communication protocols than that.

Comment: The feature is to download map tiles to a mbtiles database. A can download maps from its internal map sources (in this case the mbtiles file is stored in A's folder). B provides additional map sources to A (useful to some users only), and if users download these maps they are stored in B's folder (they must be deleted upon B uninstall). The download logic is done by A. Additionnally, users can download to existing maps, and can cancel downloads. In this case, I want to use transactions to effectively cancel (rather than stop) the download.

Comment: Seems I have no choice, I'll probably go for removing the transaction, download to a tmp folder and copy at the end if the user didn't cancel. It will only change the behavior of downloading to an existing db, transactions are not needed when creating a new one. Thanks again for confirming that direct file access is not possible.